# Using javascript setting date format to textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

in this JavaScript code first the date appears and then time in the textbox. when the textbox is clicked a calender opens with date and time. after selection both appears in the textbox.

after selection i want to remove time from it and the date should remain in the textbox.

```
<script>
$('#<%=_txtDate.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: '2015/01/01'
});
$('#<%=_txtDate.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
    value: '2015/01/01 05:03',
    step: 10
});
</script>
```

Comment: "remove time from it" is ambiguous as in remove time from which field?  Moreover, have you tried the `dateFormat` property of datetimepicker  ? I mean `$('#<%=_txtDate.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',value: '2015/01/01 05:03',step: 10});`

Answer (score 0):

If the `datetimepicker` plugin has an onChange event, I'd use that instead of this:

```
$('#<%=_txtDate.ClientID %>').on("input", function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var val = elem.val();
    var newVal = val.split(' ')[0];
    elem.val(newVal);
});
```

But that should work.

Alternatively (and better), the `datetimepicker` plugin should have a format you can use, eg:

```
$('#<%=_txtDate.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: '2015/01/01',
    dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
});
```

EDIT:
Actually, a better solution would be to use a `.datepicker` instead of a `.datetimepicker` - if you don't want the time, why ask the user for it?